# libGDX - Scrolling background by dragging mouse

Tags: java, android, background, libgdx

I'm trying to make a mouse-scrollable background using libGDX. 
I've already made the background to loop infinitely, but I have no idea how to make it to scroll by dragging the mouse. 
Is the InputProcessor the only way to make this or is there an easier way? If so, do you know any tutorials about using the mouseDrag-method in InputProcessor? 
I'm just a noob with libGDX, so if possible write specific replies please.

Comment: You should definitely use InputProcessor to detect anything dealing with interaction between user and game, but your question is a little too broad. You should post some code example of what you already tried or what you are having a hard time with before your question gets down voted to oblivion. Learn screen and world coordinates. This helped me a lot when I first started out: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gesture listener

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection

pan: A user drags a finger across the screen. The detector will report the current touch coordinates as well as the delta between the current and previous touch positions. Useful to implement camera panning in 2D.

```
@Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        camera.position.x += deltaX;
        camera.update();
        return false;
    }
```

With this code you are going to move your camera whenever you are dragging your mouse (finger on devices)

Read the link from the documentation.

Comment: Would this be the answer? His question was on mouse movement... Input Processor would at least have public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) & scrolled(int amount)

Comment: @islander_zero scrolled is for mouse scroll, this is the answer, I've already done this

Comment: I used the gesture detection system. I made own class for the gesture detection but my attempt stopped when my main class says: "The constructor GestureDetector(GestureListenerC) is undefined" (GestureListenerC is the name of the Gesture detection class

EDIT: I got it to work! I just made local variables to the main class. Do you have any idea how to add a friction so it would scroll little bit after I release my finger?

Comment: @VVahla I do. Don't forget to accept my answer! https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/GestureDetectorTest.java This does exactly what you want.